# Returning a value from database after writing in data as function return

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm sending my database a string to write into a database. I have 2 fields, one called num that's set to auto increment, and one called cards into which my string is written. So far I've been able to get my php to write the variable into the database, but now I would like it to return the num associated with it, so I can use it on my page. Can anyone help me how to write that, I'm new to php. I guess I need another sql query? (I want it to echo the num column of the row I've just written in, instead of "Records added successfully.").

php:

```
// Attempt MySQL server connection *
$link = mysqli_connect

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$cards = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['cards']);  //get data from javascript

$sql = "INSERT INTO drafts (cards) VALUES ('$cards')"; }
mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo mysqli_insert_id($link);
} else {
    echo "failed!";
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

js:

```
function writeDraft() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/write.php',
                type: 'get', //data type post/get
                data: {
                    cards: output
                },
                complete: function (response) {
                    $('#draftNum').text(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('Bummer: there was an error!');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
writeDraft();
```

Comment: I think you want http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php. Also, in the future be sure to remove your passwords/usernames.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_insert_id() will do the job

```
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    echo "Records added successfully with id: ".mysqli_insert_id($link);
}
```

Comment: Updated OP with current code, now nothing happens, the values don't get written into the db. I am sure the variable output is there (checked with console.log), and it's a string. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: can you output the SQL string and reflect it here?

Comment: do you mean the string I want to write into the database? It gets passed from a javascript variable that's called output, and it's very long. Basically it's an empty string that gets filled by an app, and is just a very long text string.

Comment: depending on how long your text can get, you should change from `GET` to `POST` or you could run into problems. can you test the PHP page without your JS by setting some value in $cards just to make sure PHP code is fine, then you can concentrate on looking elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM drafts";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$sql = "INSERT INTO drafts (cards) VALUES ('$cards')"; }

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo $num+1, " Records added successfully.";
} 

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```